# Determine where circular dependency warning in console is coming from

Tags: node.js, typescript, circular-dependency, rollupjs

When I build my React/TypeScript component library, the Rollup build is reporting a circular dependency:

```sh
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn clean && rollup -c
$ rimraf dist

./src/index.ts → ./dist/index.esm.js, ./dist/index.js...
(!) Circular dependency
src/index.ts -> src/components/index.ts -> src/components/Compound/index.ts -> src/components/Compound/Compound.tsx -> src/index.ts
created ./dist/index.esm.js, ./dist/index.js in 4.3s
Done in 5.66s.
```

I'm trying to figure out *where* that warning is coming from. TypeScript? Rollup?
After I know this I may be able to configure it so it will actually fail the build.

I've searched and grepped through my `node_modules` but can't seem to find the origin of the warning.

`rollup.config.js`:

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import pkg from './package.json';
import ts from 'typescript';

export default {
  input: './src/index.ts',
  external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}), ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {})],
  output: [
    {
      file: `./dist/${pkg.module}`,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: `./dist/${pkg.main}`,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    postcss(),
    typescript({
      typescript: ts,
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
      tsconfigDefaults: {
        exclude: [
          '**/*.spec.ts',
          '**/*.test.ts',
          '**/*.stories.ts',
          '**/*.spec.tsx',
          '**/*.test.tsx',
          '**/*.stories.tsx',
          'node_modules',
          'bower_components',
          'jspm_packages',
          'dist',
        ],
        compilerOptions: {
          sourceMap: true,
          declaration: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es5"],
    "module": "esNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules",],
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

So, my question is not how to fix the reported circular dependency, but rather, **from where is the circular dependency warning in the console output coming from?**

*Node v14.18.2, TypeScript 3.9.10, React 16.14.0, Rollup 2.70.0*

Comment: Does Rollup not give you a Stack Trace? I've seen circular dependencies cause problems in webpack before, but I've always managed to get a stack trace which helped me track it down.

Comment: Not providing stack trace by default at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the source of the warning [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/master/cli/run/batchWarnings.ts#L95) in the Rollup code.

Wasn't finding it because I hadn't considered that they would handle the "dependency" vs. "dependencies" verbiage *bangs head against wall*

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: Please see the bolded text in the original question. IMO it's a direct answer to my question